# What CSS framework to use only for controls (buttons, inputs etc), not for page layout?

Tags: css, frameworks, web-controls

I need to style some website, but I dont' need responsive design, columns and other layout features. I want just to have non-default buttons, inputs, checkbox and other controls and to have the same look in IE, FF and WebKit.

What should I use? Is any frameworks for this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery UI. Just add this to your website

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

## How to use

---

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").button()
})
```

CHECK THIS [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xJRc3/)

READ MORE [**HERE**](http://jqueryui.com/button/)

Answer (score 0):

twitter's bootstrap looks better and more promising: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/